# how to remove generate-id in sharepoint designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

```
 <h2 class="demoHeaders">Tabs </h2>
    <div id='tabs'>
```

Anytime i save the code in SP Designer 2010 the div changes to:

```
  <div id='tabs{generate-id()}'>
```

The trick in SP Designer was to create a variable and then use it but it doesn't work in SP Designer 2010.
Any ideas?

Comment: What code have you tried already that isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

You need create a parameter:

```
<xsl:param name="videolinkshow" />
```

So,

```
<div id="back{$videolinkshow}"></div>
```

Comment: Creating a parameter or giving id in braces (e.g. <div id="{divId}"></div>) did not work. Any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I blogged this here:
http://geekswithblogs.net/naijacoder/archive/2010/08/20/141405.aspx
Hope that helps

Comment: please add some insights from your article rather than just shameless plug your blog, please! :-)

Comment: Anders anything wrong with what i did? No Idea

Comment: As i said: post relevant info in your answer and **then** link to your blog, else your answer might get misunderstood as overt self-promotion. Also we want our answers to stay in the site, since external links tend to become stale quite fast. Read more in our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)

Comment: You didnt fix it thou ;)

Comment: I will fix it for sure